# React Role Based Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i am working on react and i want to add diffrent routes like admin and driver. I have two route object for each claims.I am getting user's role from api and i want to showing route by role(claim)

what i have tried,

i added that condition line -> Role==="Admin"?  but i got error that Cannot find menuItem
what should i do? thanks in advance

```
const getRole="Admin" //for example


const admin= {
id: 'dashboard',
title: '',
type: 'group',
children: [
    {
        id: 'default',
        title: 'addShipment',
        type: 'item',
        url: '/dashboard/addShipment',
        icon: icons.IconDashboard,
        breadcrumbs: false
    },
    {
            id: 'default',
            title: 'showShipment',
            type: 'item',
            url: '/dashboard/showShipment',
            icon: icons.IconDashboard,
            breadcrumbs: false
    }
    ]
};
 const driver= {
    id: 'dashboard',
    title: '',
    type: 'group',
    children: [
        {
                id: 'default',
                title: 'showShipment',
                type: 'item',
                url: '/dashboard/showShipment',
                icon: icons.IconDashboard,
                breadcrumbs: false
        }
        ]
    };

{Role==="Admin"?
    (
     const menuItem = { 
        items: [admin]
    };
   )
  :(
   const menuItem = { 
        items: [driver]
    };
  )
const MenuList = () => {

const navItems = menuItem?.items.map((item) => {
    switch (item.type) {
        case 'group':
            return <NavGroup key={item.id} item={item} />;
        default:
            return (
                <Typography key={item.id} variant="h6" color="error" align="center">
                    Menu Items Error
                </Typography>
            );
    }
});

return <>{navItems}</>;};

export default MenuList;
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement role-based route protection? Can you edit your post to include the relevant routing code you are trying to restrict access to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the right way to initialize a variable:

```
{Role==="Admin"?
    (
     const menuItem = { 
        items: [admin]
    };
   )
  :(
   const menuItem = { 
        items: [driver]
    };
  )
}
```

The variable `menuItem` is only present within the scope of that condition.
If you want to use a ternary operator try this:

```
const menuItem = Role === "Admin" ? { items: [admin] } : { items: [driver] }
```

OR

```
const menuItem = { items: [Role === "Admin" ? admin: driver] }
```